# Unable to access MEDIA_ROOT in python file

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following error

> 'function' object has no attribute 'MEDIA_ROOT'

My settings.py file has the following for MEDIA_ROOT.

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '/Client/media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/Client/media/'
```

I'm running the following code inside my views.py to see if a directory already exists. If it does not then create it.

```
from django.conf import settings
def uploadphoto(request, clientid): 
    path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/Orders/' + str(orderid)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
```

I have an old project using the same version of Django (1.10.2) that I use the same method and it works just fine. Though for this project I'm unable to run this if statement. Any idea what I'm missing? I've gone through my old project and from what I can tell everything is the same.

Comment: I'm guessing that in your `views.py` file, you define your own function named `settings`, which is replacing the imported module of the same name.

Comment: @JohnGordon - That would be it. I have a page called with a  bunch of settings and i did use the function called settings. Thanks for pointing that out to me. I'll change the function name to adminsettings or something.